How can this lowest degree monic polynomial whose root is a vector correspond to the definition of the minimal polynomial?
Let $V$ be a finite dimension vector space. $T\in \mathscr L(V)$ and $v\in V$.
Let $S_v = \{ P\in \mathbb C [X], P(T)(v)=0\}$
And let $P_v \in S_v$ be the monic polynomial of lowest degree of $S_v$.
Apparently $P_v$ is the "minimal polynomial" relative to $T(v)$. But I can't find the connection between the definition of a minimal polynomial and $P_v$.
$\mathbb C$ sure is a field. But according to the definition of a minimal polynomial, $T(v) \in V$ so $V$ should be an extension field of $\mathbb C$. I don't see how it is the case. $\mathbb C$ is not even included in $V$.
Can anyone tell me where I am getting it wrong?
Thanks.

Remove the v, what do you get? Also $P(T)$ is a linear endomorphism, not a polynomial. You don’t apply $P$ to $T(v)$ but $P(T)$ to $v$

Are you saying that $P_v$ does not meet the requirements for being a minimal polynomial?

Minimal polynomial for an element in a field extension has a different meaning than minimal polynomial in the context of vector space and linear transformations over a field. Though the definitions are almost identical, and the terminology is the same, the context is different.

@AnuradhaN. Yes but I think the linear algebra definition here is not suited since no endomorphism (nor matrix) is being canceled here

You can take the matrix associated to the linear transformation and think of it as a polynomial equation in the matrix.  (Also, $P(T)$ is a linear endomorphism from the space ${\cal{L}}(V)$ to itself).

The constant term in the polynomial corresponds to the constant multiplied by the identity matrix (or identity transformation).

What do you mean by requirements? Minimal polynomials are easily defined over any algebra. For field extension it is just a particular case of $k-algebra$

@julio_es_sui_glace I get your first comment, but the problem is the same for $v$: the vector $v$ belongs to $V$ and how can we see $V$ as a field extension of $\mathbb C$ ($\mathbb C$ being the field over which the polynomial takes its coefficients)? To reply to your question, I am just asking if you say that $P_v$ is not a minimal polynomial

Why do you want to see $V$ as a field extension? The algebra you are working with is $\mathbb{C} [T] \subset \mathcal L (\mathbb C )$

@julio_es_sui_glace Well I was assuming it was a minimal polynomial in the field theory "sense". I based myself on this question. Could it be that $P_v$ is a minimal polynomial in the linear algebra sense? But as I stated to Anuradha N. there isn't any endomorphism (nor matrix) that's being canceled here. What's canceled is its value at $v$.

Yes this is why it is « relative to v », you can see this as a minimal polynomial through the prism of $\operatorname{ev}_v$

Wikipedia says: "More formally, a minimal polynomial is defined relative to a field extension $E/F$ and an element of the extension field $E/F$". If it is relative to $v\in V$ then $V$ should be seen as a field extension? Also, what does $ev_v$ stand for? I am not familiar with algebra over fields (just quickly checked the encyclopedia page).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You appear to be confusing two variations of the notion of minimal polynomial of a vector space endomorphism, both defined in terms of a specific element but of different algebraic structures.
The simplest (to define) notion of minimal polynomial is that of a vector space endomorphism$~\phi$ of some vector space$~V$ over a field$~K$: it is the monic generator of the kernel of the substitution map $X:=\phi$ from $K[X]$ to the $K$-algebra $\mathcal L(V,V)$ of endomorphisms of$~V$. In other word it is the minimal degree monic polynomial $P$ such that $P[\phi]=0\in\mathcal L(V,V)$.
When $v\in V$ is a particular vector, one could instead just require that $P[\phi](v)=0\in V$, which in general may have a lower degree monic solution that the minimal polynomial (it will always divide the minimal polynomial). This is the $P_v$ of your question. It is equal to the minimal polynomial of the restriction of  $\phi$ to the smallest $\phi$-stable subspace containing  $v$, namely the subspace spanned by the vectors $\phi^k(v)$ for $k\in\Bbb N$.
Finally when $a$ is an element of a field extension $L/K$, the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$ is the minimal polynomial of the $K$-vector space endomorphism of$~L$ given by multiplication by$~a$. This is the monic generator of the kernel of the substitution map $X:=a$ from $K[X]$ to the $K$-algebra $L$, in other words the minimal degree monic polynomial $P\in K[X]$ such that $P[a]=0\in L$. There is no direct relation with the polynomials $P_v$.
